# Recovering a program from a locked AVR

Tags: avr, fuse-bits

How can a program from an AVR be recovered when its lock fuse bits are set?

Comment: Question doen't make any sense!

Comment: Edited the question, I think this is what the question meant to ask.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for assistance with software piracy.

Comment: Etch the plastic top off, make holes in the passivation layer with an E-beam and start probing. (humm, maybe I should turn this into an answer...)

Comment: The point of the lock fuse bits is to lock the device. You need to hack the device to read the code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking, "How can I recover a program from an AVR microcontroller when the fusebits are set to protect the code?" then the answer is that you can't. That's what they are for.

Comment: You can't easily but there are ways to get around those limitations, but the effort required is often not worth what you get.

Comment: ... but if you have the resources  to undertake that effort, you certainly don't need to ask how.